# Openlayers CQL DWITHIN returns errors

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, cql-filter

I'm trying to use CQL but I guess I do it wrong because I get pink layer in return and error in geoserver :

> Binary geometry filter, but first expression is not a property name?
>   (it's a class org.geotools.filter.LiteralExpressionImpl)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary geometry filter, but first
>   expression is not a property name?

This is how I try to do the DWITHIN (get all lines at 200 meter from buildings)

```
wLayer.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER': "DWITHIN('geom',querySingle('Buildings','geom','INCLUDE'),200,meters)"})
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the single quotes around `geom`:

```
wLayer.mergeNewParams(
  {
    'CQL_FILTER': "DWITHIN(geom,querySingle('Buildings','geom','INCLUDE'),200,meters)"
  }
)
```

I additionally suggest to first try it with a fixed point as second argument:

```
wLayer.mergeNewParams(
  {
    'CQL_FILTER': "DWITHIN(geom,POINT(7 15),200,meters)"
  }
)
```

Comment: The point works , but when I try queryCollection I get error that more than 1000 items are brought back and I'm sure there are much less than 1000.